# Can I get Geoserver to return a WMS in gnomonic projection?

Tags: geoserver, coordinate-system, wms

I need to be able to pass in the center lat and long.  I have tried using the AUTO Namespace for SRS (which works) but this only supports a few projections, the closest being orthographic.

I have found this link for ArcGIS http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//015400000605000000 which says I could pass in the whole projection, rather than just an EPSG code.  I haven't actually been able to find if this even possible with GeoServer.

I am using GeoServer 2.5.1.

Answer (score 1):

OK it's open source.  So change it yourself.

Code is implemented here

http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/referencing/operation/projection/Gnomonic.html

CRS is documented here

http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/nonstandardautonamespace.html